# DWORD and VARTYPE equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pinvoke, marshalling

I am using an API which contains following methods:

```
BOOL GetItemPropertyDescription (HANDLE hConnect, int PropertyIndex, DWORD *pPropertyID, VARTYPE *pVT, BYTE *pDescr, int BufSize);
BOOL ReadPropertyValue (HANDLE hConnect, LPCSTR Itemname, DWORD PropertyID, VARIANT *pValue);
```

What will be equivalent in c#?

What is the meaning of `DWORD, VARTYPE, VARIANT` datatypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fairly complete table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) at **Table 1**. Try looking.

```
DWORD is uint
VARTYPE is an ushort (but you have a ref ushort there) 
        or much better a VarEnum (but you have a ref VarEnum there)
        (VarEnum is defined under System.Runtime.InteropServices)
VARIANT is object (but you have a ref object there)
```

There is an article here on the marshaling of VARIANT: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/24/56642.aspx

The exact PInvoke is complex to write, it depends on the direction of the parameters and their exact specification. Is `pPropertyID` a pointer to a single `DWORD`, or is a pointer to the first `DWORD` of an "array"? And who "fills" the value pointed at, the caller or the callee or both? The same for all the other pointers.

Technically all/part of the `ref`s could be `out` if they are filled by the callee.

By the name of the methods, their pinvoke could be:

```
[DllImport("YourDll.dll")]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] // This line is optional, and it's implicit
bool GetItemPropertyDescription(IntPtr hConnect, 
                                int propertyIndex, 
                                out uint pPropertyID, 
                                out VarEnum pVT, 
                                out IntPtr pDescr, 
                                int bufSize);

[DllImport("YourDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] // This line is optional, and it's implicit
bool ReadPropertyValue(IntPtr hConnect, 
                       string itemName, 
                       uint propertyID, 
                       out object pValue);
```