# SetWindowHookEx always returns NULL

Tags: c#, c++, setwindowshookex

I am trying to set CBT_HOOK to detect messages like WM_DESTROY, WM_CLOSE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_CREATE and so on - so it should be non-global hook.

I wrote simple DLL in C++:

DllMain.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        if (hInst == NULL)
            hInst = hModule;

        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

dll.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

HWND hWnd;
HHOOK CBTHookID;

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("inside hook proc!"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
    return CallNextHookEx(CBTHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) bool SetHook(DWORD threadID, HWND _hWnd)
    {
        hWnd = _hWnd;
        CBTHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTHookProc, 0, threadID);

        return CBTHookID ? true : false;
    }
}

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void RemoveHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(CBTHookID);
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("unhooked"), TEXT("ok"), MB_OK);
    }
}
```

And want to set hook from c# application:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\..\dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr SetHook(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport(@"C:\Users\..\dll.dll")]
public static extern bool RemoveHook(IntPtr hHook);

IntPtr hook = IntPtr.Zero;

private void buttonSetHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // proc - the process I want to set hook to

     hook = SetHook((IntPtr)proc.MainWindowHandle);
     MessageBox.Show(hook.ToString());
}
```

The hook is always 0. I've tried to pass proc.hande and Thread id with hightest priority for this process (ProcessThread.Id with Hightest ThreadPriorityLevel), but SetHook always returns 0.

So, what should I pass as "threadID" to SetWindowHookEx? Or the problem is somewere else?

P.S. I use VisualStudio and for this project I run it as administrator, OS - windows 10.

**EDIT:**
With the help of the commentators, I have now working solution:

DllMain.cpp

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE hInst; // A handle to the DLL module

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        if (hInst == NULL)
            hInst = hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

dll.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern HINSTANCE hInst; // A handle to the DLL module

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("HCBT_ACTIVATE"), TEXT("inside hook"), MB_OK);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam); //according to MSDN, first parameter is ignored
}

extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool SetHook(DWORD threadID)
    {
        CBTHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTHookProc, hInst , threadID);
        return CBTHookID != 0;
    }
}

extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool RemoveHook()
    {
        int removed = UnhookWindowsHookEx(CBTHookID);
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("unhooked"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
        return removed != 0;
    }
}
```

And c# code:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\..\dll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool SetHook(uint hWnd);

[DllImport(@"C:\Users\..\dll.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool RemoveHook();

bool hook = false;

private void buttonSetHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    // proc - the process I want to set hook to

    var threadID = (uint)proc.Threads[0].Id;
    hook = SetHook(ThreadID); //This works, for example, for "notepad.exe" which has only one thread. May not work prorerly with other processes!

    if(hook)
      MessageBox.Show("Hooked!");
    else
      MessageBox.Show("Some error occured");
}

private void buttonRemoveHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hook)
        RemoveHook();
}
```

[screenshot of hooked notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rTss.png)

Comment: "To get extended error information, call GetLastError." What does that return?

Comment: `SetHook` takes two parameters, but you're only passing one. That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @AlanStokes thank you for your answer! I deleted hWnd from SetHook parameters, as i never used it anywhere. Now if I pass proc.handle, proc.mainWindowHandle or proc.Id GetLastError returns error code 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (The parameter is incorrect), if I pass Thread id with highest priority for the process I want to set hook to, GetLastError returns 1428 ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD (Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle). I think this is where the problem is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077400/dword-and-vartype-equivalent-in-c-sharp) suggests your C# function imports are off - try `uint` for the `DWORD` parameters. Your return types are definitely messed up. Why are you specifying `IntPtr` return value for a `bool` function (`SetHook`) and `bool` for a `void` function (`RemoveHook`)?

Comment: You need to pass the handle of the DLL to `SetWindowsHoookEx`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you a lot, now everything works correct.

Comment: @computerfreaker thank you too, I've corrected these errors.